# Task scheduler runs python and gives activation error

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, environment

I'm running a Python script on Python 3.8.8 and it works as it should be. But when I try to  make it a scheduled task, it crashes.

To debug, I have created a simple task that just opens Python interpreter and it opens the interpreter with a warning: "the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load".

So when I import a library that is available in my environment, it gives out an import error.

I assume this is the reason why my scheduled task crashes (it tries to import a library but since the environment is not activated, it crashes).

Any solution ideas? [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A48R1.png)

Thank you

Comment: Did you read the warning properly?

Comment: Yes, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (with dlls for ssl), that was linked with conda and python 3.7.1+. To mitigate I had to create a `.bat` loading conda environment before starting my script.
The `.bat` is the file launched by the tasks scheduler.

After creating a conda environment `D:\MyScript\venv_conda_3_9` (might not be useful in your case), and installing then required libs :

In a `start_script.bat`

```
call C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
call conda activate D:\MyScript\venv_conda_3_9
call python D:\MyScript\myscript.py
call conda deactivate
```

`conda_hook.bat` allows you to have conda environments in consoles : https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8702#issuecomment-494163721

Comment: This works as a nice workaround for my problem, thank you! Any suggestion to make it work in the background? (currently, it pop-ups the command interface)

Comment: For that I guess you need to have a look at : https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window/9042